# Does JBOSS 5_1_0 GA support packaging EJBs in WAR?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, java-ee-6

I have beans annotated with `@Stateless` packaged in WEB-INF/lib/*.jar. Does JBoss 5.1.0 GA support these type of EJB deployment mentioned [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipio.html#gippi)

Or do I need to package my beans always in an EAR and provide JBoss descriptors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JBoss 5 is a [**Java EE 5 EJB 3.0 Compatible Implementation**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/compatibility-javaee5-jsp-141098.html).
**EJB3.1 spec** (part Java EE 6) lets `.war` files to contain EJBs and is not part **JBoss 5**, you can try with JBoss AS 6 or any higher version